# Evalute triple sum $ \sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{n \geq 0}\sum_{p\geq 0} \frac{m!n!p!}{(m+n+p+2)!}$

Tags: summation, factorial, alternative-proof, gamma-function, harmonic-numbers

I had a triple $T$ sum to evaluate

> $$\sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{n \geq 0}\sum_{p\geq 0} \frac{m!n!p!}{(m+n+p+2)!}$$ where $!$ denotes factorials.

The managed to find the closed form  of it, $\displaystyle \frac{\pi^2}{4}$ however, my work is quite tedious. My work follows as

The infinite triple sum
$T$ can be reduced to $$T=\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{k^2}
+\frac{1}{k(k+1)^2}+\cdots\right)\\=\sum_{k\geq1}\sum_{l\geq 0}\left(\prod_{j\geq 0}(k+j)\right)^{-1}\frac{l!}{k+l}$$ where $l,j,k$ are some dummy  variable. Further by partial fraction decomposition, the latter expression can be reduced to the following  expression $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\sum_{l\geq 0} \sum_{q=0}^l{l\choose q}\frac{(-1)^q}{(k+q)(k+l)}=\\ \sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\sum_{q=0 ,q\neq l}{l\choose q}\frac{(-1)^q}{(k+q)(k+l)}+\sum_{l\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^l}{(k+l)^2}\right)$$ Using the  linearity and we see that the last sum we have $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\sum_{l\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^l}{(k+l)^2}=\sum_{r\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2r+1)^2}=\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}\cdots(1)$$ and the former sum $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\sum_{l\geq 1}\sum_{q=0, q\neq  l}\frac{(-1)^q}{l-q}\left(\frac{1}{k+q}-\frac{1}{k+l}\right){l\choose q}=\sum_{l\geq 1}\sum_{q=0, q\neq  l}\frac{(-1)^q(H_l-H_q)}{l-q}{l\choose q}$$ expanding the sum we obtained the telescoping series giving us $$1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\cdots =\frac{\pi^2}{8}\cdots(2)$$ Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$  we obtained $T=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$

My first query, *How can we resolve  this sum in others way?*

Moreover,with this motivation I  wish to generalize  the triple  sum $T(k)$ for one parameter $k\geq 0$  as

> $$\sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{n \geq 0}\sum_{p\geq 0} \frac{m!n!p!}{(m+n+p+k)!}=?$$

Following  work as above I find no fine clues to handle it.

My second query, *How to handle the generalized sum?*

Thank you !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the poles and residues of the $\Gamma$ function, or just by creative telescoping, we have
$$\sum_{p\geq 0}\frac{p!}{(p+K)!}=\frac{1}{(K-1)\Gamma(K)}\tag{1} $$
hence
$$\sum_{m,n,p\geq 0}\frac{m!n!p!}{(p+m+n+2)!}=\sum_{m,n\geq 0}\frac{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{(m+n+1)\Gamma(m+n+2)}=\sum_{m,n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(m+n+1)}\int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^m\,dx\tag{2}$$
and by rearranging
$$\sum_{m,n,p\geq 0}\frac{m!n!p!}{(p+m+n+2)!}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{m,n\geq 0}\frac{x^n(1-x)^m}{(m+n+1)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-x)-\log(x)}{1-2x}\,dx\tag{3}$$
equals
$$ 2\int_{0}^{1/2}-\log\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{1-2x} \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{z}{1+z}}{=}2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log(z)}{1-z^2}\,dz=2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}.\tag{4} $$

---

This approach can be generalized. For instance
$$\sum_{m,n,p\geq 0}\frac{m!n!p!}{(p+m+n+3)!}=\sum_{m,n\geq 0}\frac{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{(m+n+2)^2\Gamma(m+n+2)}=\sum_{m,n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(m+n+2)^2}\int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^m\,dx\tag{2'}$$
and by rearranging
$$\sum_{m,n,p\geq 0}\frac{m!n!p!}{(p+m+n+3)!}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{m,n\geq 0}\frac{x^n(1-x)^m}{(m+n+2)^2}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\text{Li}_2(1-x)-(1-x)\text{Li}_2(x)}{x(1-3x+2x^2)}\,dx\tag{3'}$$
equals
$$ 2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x\text{Li}_2(1-x)-(1-x)\text{Li}_2(x)}{x(1-3x+2x^2)} \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{z}{1+z}}{=}2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1+z}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)}{z(1-z)}\,dz\tag{4'} $$
or
$$ 2\int_{0}^{1}\left[z\,\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1+z}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)+(1-z)\,\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2-z}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-z}{2-z}\right)\right]\frac{dz}{z}.$$
By integration by parts this expression boils down to Euler sums with weight $\leq 3$.
After a massive amount of computations we have
$$\boxed{\sum_{a,b,c\geq 0}\frac{a!b!c!}{(a+b+c+3)!}=\color{red}{\frac{13}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{2}\log(2)}.}$$

Comment: Thank you very much Jack. It seems like getting the closed form for  general version is tough job, here.

Comment: @NarenNaruto: the case $k=4$ should be manageable without too much pain, pisco's work might come handy for $k=5$ (serious job there) and for $k\geq 6$ heavy software assistance becomes necessary, I guess.

Comment: I dont get pisco's work, can you elaborate a bit,if possible.  I see, if there is any update from  you let me know. :D

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffd]{\sum_{m\ \geq\ 0}\sum_{n\ \geq\ 0}\sum_{p\ \geq\ 0} {m!\, n!\, p! \over \pars{m + n + p + 2}!}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{m!\, n! \over \pars{m + n + 1}!}
\sum_{p = 0}^{\infty} {\Gamma\pars{m + n + 2}\Gamma\pars{p + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{m + n + p + 3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{m!\, n! \over \pars{m + n + 1}!}
\sum_{p = 0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^{m + n + 1}\pars{1 - x}^{\, p}\,\dd x
\\ = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\Gamma\pars{m + 1}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{m + n + 2}}\,
x^{m + n + 1}\
\overbrace{\sum_{p = 0}^{\infty}\pars{1 - x}^{\, p}}^{\ds{1 \over x}}\
\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}y^{m}\pars{1 - y}^{n}\,\dd y}x^{m + n}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\pars{xy}^{m}}
\braces{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{x\pars{1 - y}}^{\, n}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x\,\dd y \over \pars{1 - xy}\pars{1 - x + xy}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\pars{y - 1}
\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \pars{y - 1}x + 1} +
y\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over 1 - xy}}\,{\dd y \over 2y - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y} - \ln\pars{1 - y} \over 2y - 1}\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{y \over 1 - y} \,{\dd y \over 2y - 1}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{y/\pars{1 - y}\ =\ t}{=}\,\,\,&
-\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t^{2}}\,\dd t =
-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t^{2}}\,\dd t -
\int_{1}^{0}{\ln\pars{1/t} \over 1 - \pars{1/t}^{2}}
\,\pars{-\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t^{2}}\,\dd t =
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid navy]{\pi^{2} \over 4}\
\approx\ 2.4674
\end{align}

---

---

Note that
\begin{align}
-2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t^{2}}\,\dd t & =
-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t -
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 + t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t +
\int_{0}^{-1}{\ln\pars{-t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,
-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t +
\int_{0}^{-1}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1} - \mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{-1}
\quad\pars{\ DiLogarithm\ }
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi^{2} \over 6} - \pars{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 12}} =
{\pi^{2} \over 4}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for dropping your ideas. :)

Comment: @NarenNaruto You're welcome ${\bullet \quad\bullet \choose \smile}$

Answer (score 1):

I am treating the case $k=4$ in a separate answer since the rendering times are a bit long. We have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{a!b!c!}{(a+b+c+4)!}=\sum_{b,c\geq 0}\frac{B(b+1,c+1)}{(3+b+c)^2(2+b+c)}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{b,c\geq 0}\frac{x^b(1-x)^c}{(3+b+c)^2(2+b+c)}\,dx $$
and the RHS equals
$$\small \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{s\geq 0}\frac{1}{(s+3)^2(s+2)}\sum_{b=0}^{s}x^b(1-x)^{s-b}\,dx =\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{s\geq 0}\left[\frac{1}{s+2}-\frac{1}{s+3}-\frac{1}{(s+3)^2}\right]\frac{x^{s+1}-(1-x)^{s+1}}{2x-1}\,dx$$
which Mathematica is able to evaluate as
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{a!b!c!}{(a+b+c+4)!}=\color{red}{6-\frac{\pi^2}{2}+\pi^2\log(2)-\frac{13}{2}\zeta(3)}\approx 0.0929163927751. $$